# What must be done that Shiny evaluates the expression from a textInput correctly to filter a dataset?

Tags: r, shiny

I want the expression in the `textInput()` to be evaluated and my dataset filtered accordingly. I for example want to write an expression like `mass > 100` into the `textInput()`.

I know that this has something to do with non-standart-evaluation but i cannot get it to work. Any help is apprechiated.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  textInput("txt", "Filter Data"),
  reactableOutput(outputId = "table")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  output$table = renderReactable({
    req(input$txt)
    dplyr::starwars %>%
      filter(input$txt) %>%
      reactable()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I recommend against this approach which would create a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against this approach which would create a security hole.

A way to do this would be `filter(eval(parse(text = input$txt)))`. But again, don't.

Consider what happens if the user types in, literally: `{ cat("I can run arbitrary code on the server") ; mass > 100 }`

[image]